# FormSubmit "Same Origin Policy" Error Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, form-submit, same-origin-policy

So I using this super cool [FormSubmit](https://formsubmit.io/) service for a contact submission in my Angular app. I am sending the form data with help of Angular `HttpClient`.

Below is my service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormsubmitService {

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  sendForm(formData: object) {
    console.log('Form Data:', formData);
    this.httpClient.post('https://formsubmit.io/send/<TOKEN HERE>', formData)
      .subscribe((response) => console.log(response), (error) => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

I get this errorr `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://formsubmit.io/error/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)` in my console log after submission.

Any ideas how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to access resources from a different origin, it needs to allow it with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. When you post to `formsubmit.io/send` it returns the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

There is no problem yet because `formsubmit.io` explicitly says it allows access from any origin (*). However, because of some error unrelated to CORS, it redirects you using the `Location` header to `formsubmit.io/error`.

```
Location: /error/?error=...
```

Your browser automatically sends a `GET` to that address. This new address does not send any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and thus your browser blocks it. You can view the error in the URL of the request in the `Network` tab of your Dev Tools and fix it.

[image]
Alternatively you can disable CORS in your browser for the duration of development. There are plugins for both Chrome and Firefox that can achieve that.